# following-sibling not getting desired xpath in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am facing an issue with the **following-sibling**. 
I am not getting the desired result.
I want to get the XPath of **9,730.59** by the following-sibling XPath method.

```
<tfoot xpath="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"><b>Weekly GP$</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">2,646.68</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">2,812.00</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">2,647.16</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">1,624.75</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"><b>Total</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">9,730.59</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">11,401.29</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"><b>Bank(20%)</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">2,280.26</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"><b>Payout</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">9,121.03</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

My XPath is :

```
//div[@class='custome-responsive']//tfoot//b[contains(text(),'Total')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text `Total` is in the child `<b>` tag, the `<td>` you are trying to locate is in fact its uncle element. You need to go back to the `<b>` parent

```
//b[contains(text(),'Total')]/../following-sibling::td[1]
```

Or use `following` instead of `following-sibling`

```
//b[contains(text(),'Total')]/following::td[1]
```